Movie trailer: army on a mission, woman survives but wasn't meant to
Maybe half a year ago I saw a movie trailer, the problem is I don't know the name of the movie but I remember some of the trailer and it happens like this.
It is an army that goes to a mission but instead something unexpected happens, they were shot by friendly fire but a woman survives. I don't even remember all the details in the trailer but I remember that the woman that survives was not meant to be alive and her family was told that she was died.
There hides with refugees in order to survive and there is another woman that is helping her.
The movie was made in 2015 or 2014. Among the soldiers there is only one woman and she is the only survivor; they were hit by a missile and her family were told that she is dead. She has a young daughter.
So please if you know the movie I am talking about or you can guess, please answer me back.

I suspect that you saw a trailer to the TV series American Odyssey.
(aka Odyssey in the UK).
The plot is very similar to your description.
On a mission in North Africa, the main character finds evidence that a US security company has been funding terrorists. Later her unit is attacked and she is the only survivor. The remainder is essentially her journey to keep one step ahead of the people who want to remove all traces interwoven with investigations and cover-ups in the USA.
She has a young daughter and her family are told that she is dead.
More details in the wikipedia article.

It's the one I was looking for.
